# subneting question

Tags: ip

i have doubt on this question, please clarify

You are designing a subnet mask for the 172.16.0.0 network. You want 80 subnets with up to 300 hosts on each subnet. Which subnet mask should you use?

Comment: Sorry. You’ll have to do your own homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have 65534 host on subnet 172.16.0.0 /16 or 255.255.0.0

you can have 254 host on subnet 172.16.0.0 /24 or 255.255.255.0

you can have 510 host on subnet 172.16.0.0 /23 or 255.255.254.0 (total 128
 subnet of 510 host between 172.16.0.0 and 172.16.255.255)

according to question, you should set the subnet to /23 to cover the range of 300 host. also you have 210 extra reserve host on each subnet.

> 172.16.0.0 /23 start IP : 172.16.0.1  End IP: 172.16.1.254
>   172.16.2.0 /23 start IP : 172.16.2.1  End IP: 172.16.3.254

Comment: Your answers are inaccurate.